# Can @Resource annotation use normally without spring-framework?

Tags: java, tomcat

I've known the difference between @Resource annotation and @Autowired annotation recently, but I don't know in what scene @Resource annotation will be used before spring-framework has been invented.

I've search google and stackoverflow for any hints and don't get any reasonable explanation. Then I've tried to create a Java Web Project(use J2EE1.4, jdk1.7, tomcat 7), and create a servlet to mock Spring's autowire behavior by using @Resource annotation, but we encounter a error.

Below the code I use:

```java
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {


    public void init() throws ServletException {
        Student student=new Student("1");
    }
    public void service(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("111111111111");
    }

}
```

```java
public class TestServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource
    Student student;
    public void service(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(student);
    }

}
```

First, I visit the TestServlet to create Student java bean, and then I visit TestServlet2 to inject Student object to student property. But I encounter a error like below:

```java
javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceEnvFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceEnvFactory.java:115)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:848)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:836)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.lookupFieldResource(DefaultInstanceManager.java:538)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.processAnnotations(DefaultInstanceManager.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1133)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:853)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:506)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2538)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect J2EE1.4 to support Annotations since Annotations didn't exist until Java 5 / JavaEE 5.

Comment: ...but as for the actual error, that's a JNDI lookup failing.  I'm not really familiar with the `@Resource` annotation, but the [JavaEE docs seem to imply you need to add it to JNDI](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bncjk.html) somehow... and the Tomcat docs specify [how to do it through Tomcat settings](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much!@Powerlord Your advice is of great help, and solve my problem perfectly.This is my solution:
I create a file Context.xml in WebRoot/META-INF

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<Resource name="student" auth="Container"
     type="com.test.Student" factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory" id="5">
</Resource>
</Context>
```

```java
public class TestServlet2 extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource(name="student")
    Student student;
    public void service(ServletRequest arg0, ServletResponse arg1)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(student.getId());
    }

}
```